# Chemical Like discharge from RE 350

Tags: motorcycle, clutch, enfield-classic, enfield-bullet, royal-enfield

My royal enfield 350 classic just had a service and I just noticed a weird Chemical like foam coming out of it. It has hardened now and settled on it. I have posted the photo below. Any help as to what this might be ? It has come out of the clutch assembly side.[image]

[image]

Comment: There appears to be some this "foam" on the large bolt head above the area in question. Is the battery located behind that RE cover? Is the foam coming from that area? Battery acid would do what you are seeing. Be careful wiping this away in case it is battery acid.

Comment: Thanks @CharlieRB, I got this checked from my mechanic and he did tell me that its battery acid. Asked me to get the battery checked. even the bolt below the batter case had the same residue on it.

Comment: I will submit this as an answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be some this "foam" on the large bolt head above the area in question. Is the battery located behind that "RE" cover? Is the foam coming from that area? Battery acid would do what you are seeing. Be careful wiping this away in case it is battery acid.

Comment: The OP can get some baking soda and water to clean the effected area and neutralize the acid as well.